# Obtaining speed limit data of roads and be able to use this data on an android phone?

Tags: android, database

Companies like Google and Garmin have a database of all speed limits of each road that they use on their GPS software. I would like to access and use this information. How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1):

These companies either purchased, licensed or built their own map data, of which this information is part.

You might have some success with [OpenStreetMap](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Speed_limits). YMMV.

Comment: How would a license cost?

Answer (score 1):

Google has an API for road data.  See this link: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/speed-limits

I don't find it very accurate.  Speed limit data can be updated via their Map Maker tool.  Some of it may be gleaned off of the street view cameras, but not 100% sure that is how they collect it.

I'm also interested in learning Garmin's source for the data.  I hear it is just as bad.  Does Garmin have a similar API?